# There are extra Edge, in Object Mode

Tags: edges, object-mode

[image]Orange Edges appear, in Object Mode.
It breaks Subdivision.
[image]

https://www.dropbox.com/s/29josc8s8jgv87r/head.blend?dl=0

Comment: I'm not near my computer, but if I had to guess it's a duplicated edge, on top of the other one. See if you can move it and what's underneath. If it's a double - delete one.

Answer (score 2):

Your highlighted edge is connecting two vertices, but this edge is not separator of two face how it seems :) It is actually one face.

[image]

**Delete** those two edges and use **Knife** (K) to cut face into two.

[image]